# Areospike - how to dynamically create sets in the database using Java?

Tags: java, database, aerospike

I am trying to create an API which should allow dynamic creation of a set in an areospike database.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A record key (Key constructor in java api) uses three arguments - namespace, setname, yourkey --- whatever setname you use gets created (its a metadata on the record) - you can create maximum 1023 such set names. Once a set name is used, it cannot be easily removed from a running cluster.